# FluentSecurity with MVCSiteMapProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvcsitemapprovider, fluent-security

I was hoping to use this with MvcSiteMapProvider to hide / show menu items instead of doubling up and defining roles in my mvc.sitemap file.

I have gone through the source for 2.0alpha1 but can't seem to figure out how to do something like:

```
bool hasAccess = SecurityConfiguration.Current.HasAccess(controller, action, area)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this with the help of [kristoffer-ahl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44085/kristoffer-ahl) on the actual github project page

Here is the solution

```cs
public static bool ActionIsAllowedForUser(string area, string controllerName, string actionName)
{
    var configuration = SecurityConfiguration.Current;

    string fullControllerName = string.Format("Web.Controllers.{0}Controller", controllerName);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(area))
    {
        fullControllerName = string.Format("Web.Areas.{0}.Controllers.{1}Controller", area, controllerName);
    }

    var policyContainer = configuration.PolicyContainers.GetContainerFor(fullControllerName, actionName);
    if (policyContainer != null)
    {
        var context = SecurityContext.Current;
        var results = policyContainer.EnforcePolicies(context);
        return results.All(x => x.ViolationOccured == false);
    }
    return true;
}
```